# Asp.net development and clientside operations integration

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, frameworks, client-side

I've been using prado framework for a short time. In some projects I may be required to develop on  Microsoft's web tools platform. Can I easily integrate javascripts I'm familiar with(prototype, jquery or others) with ASP.Net as it was in prado? Or is there a Microsoft specific solution for web browser clientside operations? I develop database apps involving heavily populated input forms.

Comment: Javascript works in browsers, so no matter which server side technology you use, it will always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to use many of the built-in features of ASP.NET to handle client-side behavior, it is certainly not recommended.

So, using your existing scripts would be the preferred way to approach this situation.

Obviously, you will likely need to make some changes, but if you can get ASP.NET to render the same markup you have now, those changes should be minimal or even non-existent.

Comment: So this means, I can use popular javascript frameworks that I used with php. I imply maybe even use the same code. Thanks.